# Replace field value(s) in a String

Tags: java, guava

Using Google Guava is there String utility to easily replace string field inside like this:

```
String query = mydb..sp_mySP ${userId}, ${groupId}, ${someOtherField}
```

Where I can do something like this:

```
StringUtil.setString(query)
   .setField("userId", "123")
   .setField("groupId", "456")
   .setField("someOtherField", "12-12-12");
```

Then the resulting String would be:

```
mydb..sp_mySP 123, 456, 12-12-12
```

Of course, setting the String field patter like `${<field>}` before the operation...

Anyway, this is my approach:

```
public class StringUtil {
    public class FieldModifier {
        private String s;
        public FieldModifier(String s){
            this.s = s;
        }
        public FieldModifier setField(String fieldName, Object fieldValue){
            String value = String.valueOf(fieldValue);
            s = modifyField(s, fieldName, value);
            return new FieldModifier(s); 
        }
        public String get() {
                return s;
        }
        private String modifyField(String s, String fieldName, String fieldValue){
            String modified = "";
            return modified;
        }
    }
    public FieldModifier parse(String s){
        FieldModifier fm = new FieldModifier(s);
        return fm; 
    }
}
```

So in this case, I just need to put the actual code in the `modifyField` function that will modify the string in a straightforward way. Also if there's a way so the `parse` function be static so I can just do `StringUtil.parse(...)` without doing `new StringUtil().parse(...)` which really doesn't look good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing in Guava. You can have a look at [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html) (Spring Expression Language) which can do string templating, or other templating frameworks such as [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yeah, a template engine is probably what you want here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

```
String s = "Hey %s! Cool %s, right?";
System.out.println(String.format(s, "xybrek", "feature"));
```

Comment: This is not a "named" substitution, which I think is what xybrek asked.

Answer (score 2):

Using Guava? No.

Though an enhancement has recently been requested to support this ([see here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1142)).

Anyway, this is still doable using Apache Commons Lang's [StrSubstitutor](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html).